# Align Append button height with select2 dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-core, jquery-select2

I've customized the height of `select2` `dropdown`. but the `append` `button` height can't be customized properly.

my `html` is below

```
 <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
     <select class="form-control form-control-sm select2">
          <option value="">Select Supplier</option>
      </select>
     <div class="input-group-append">
          <input class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" type="button" value="..." />
     </div>    
 </div>
```

The customized `css` is below

```
.select2, .select2-selection__rendered {
    line-height: calc(1em + .1rem + 0px) !important;
    padding-top:5px;
}

.select2-container .select2-selection--single {
    height: calc(1.5em + .4rem + 0px) !important;
}

.select2-container--bootstrap4 .select2-selection--multiple {
    min-height: calc(1em + .75rem + 2px) !important;
}

.select2-selection__arrow {
    height: calc(1.5em + .5rem + -30px) !important;
}
```

[image: Current view is like this]

Comment: I test this code, but they are the same height. Whether it conflict with other element?

Answer (score -1):

try giving height to the 'input' tag instead of the div covering it.
eg.

```
input {
    height: 20px;
}
```

or

```
btn {
 height: 20px
}
```